# Eliminating local report extra blank pages

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services, printing, rdlc

I am printing an `RDLC` report using a class wrote with `Vb.net`.

I converted the `RDLC` report to a List of `MemoryStream` and Printing it using a `PrintDocument` Object. i used This [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) as a reference.

This is my code:

```vb
Private m_currentPageIndex As Integer
Private m_streams As IList(Of Stream)
Dim m_report As LocalReport

Public Sub New(ByVal v_report As LocalReport)


    m_report = v_report

End Sub

' Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to
' save an image for each page of the report.
Public Function CreateStream(ByVal name As String, ByVal fileNameExtension As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal mimeType As String, ByVal willSeek As Boolean) As Stream
    Dim stream As Stream = New MemoryStream()
    m_streams.Add(stream)
    Return stream
End Function

' Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
Public Sub Export(ByVal report As LocalReport)
    Dim deviceInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo>" &
        "<OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" &
        "<PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" &
        "<PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" &
        "<MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>" &
        "<MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>" &
        "<MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>" &
        "<MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>" &
        "</DeviceInfo>"
    Dim warnings As Warning()
    m_streams = New List(Of Stream)

    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, AddressOf CreateStream, warnings)

    For Each stream As Stream In m_streams
        stream.Position = 0
    Next
End Sub

' Handler for PrintPageEvents
Public Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim pageImage As New Metafile(m_streams(m_currentPageIndex))


    ' Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
    Dim adjustedRect As New Rectangle(ev.PageBounds.Left - CInt(ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX),
                                      ev.PageBounds.Top - CInt(ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY),
                                      ev.PageBounds.Width,
                                      ev.PageBounds.Height)

    ' Draw a white background for the report
    ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)

    ' Draw the report content
    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect)

    ' Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.

    m_currentPageIndex += 1
    ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count)
End Sub

Public Sub Print()

    If m_streams Is Nothing OrElse m_streams.Count = 0 Then
        Throw New Exception("Error: no stream to print.")
    End If

    Dim printDoc As New PrintDocument()
    If Not printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
        Throw New Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.")
    Else
        AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPage
        m_currentPageIndex = 0

        printDoc.Print()
    End If
End Sub

' Create a local report for Report.rdlc, load the data,
' export the report to an .emf file, and print it.
Public Sub Run()
    Export(m_report)
    Print()
End Sub
```

The problem is that this code is printing 3 extra blank pages.

I tried to set `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpaces = True`

and it doesn't fixed my problem

When debugging i found that the length of a blankpage `MemoryStream` is `408` so i tried to filter the memorystreams using the following code in `Print` Sub

```
    Dim var = m_streams.Where(Function(X) X.Length <= 408).ToList

    For Each ms As MemoryStream In var
        m_streams.Remove(ms)
    Next
```

and it eliminate blank pages. But i cannot assume that i can use this query can be used for other cases? any suggestion

**Note:**

- I accept answers in `C#`
- Code provided is from **MSDN** article linked above

**Update 1:**

- I tried to minimize page width but still have the same problem
- Report is printed without using `ReportViewer`

Comment: Exotic code, hard to see the problem it tries to solve.  The only thing that jumps out is the LocalReport.Render() overload that you use.  Right now it is the "easy" one that does not specify the PageCountMode argument that the other overloads take.  It uses PageCountMode.Estimate.  Clearly you have a good reason to use PageCountMode.Actual.

Comment: @HansPassant This code is from MSDN. I provided it link. If you know another way please provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving many tries, it looks like a blank page memory stream size is 408, so to eliminate blank page we can use the code provided

```
Dim var = m_streams.Where(Function(X) X.Length <= 408).ToList

For Each ms As MemoryStream In var
    m_streams.Remove(ms)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change the report width, many times the width make extra white pages.

Comment: Report dimensions is the dimensions of A4 paper. this is what i need

Comment: @Hadi The report sizes are not A4: A4 is 8.27 by 11.69 inches.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i tested it with dimensions you provided but it get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the .RDLC report, do you have excess white space? See the image for an example. The white space is highlighted in yellow. This area will **always** print, and appear to be blank.

If you do, try shortening the white space to surround only your table / matrix. Hover over the black border and drag the border up until it surrounds only your table. That should eliminate excess pages.

[image]

Comment: In the report designer i dont have white spaces. It is shown while printing

Comment: Well this got rid of half of my extra space... Now for the other half...